# Win32::Console::ANSI and uri_unescape

Tags: perl, winapi, terminal, escaping

When I run this script in a WinXP Terminal with CP850 the `Ü` and `ö` are displayed correct. When I uncomment the `use Win32::Console::ANSI;` line the output is broken.
Is this behavior expectable or is this a bug?

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(cp850)';

use Encode qw(decode_utf8);
use URI::Escape qw(uri_unescape);
#use Win32::Console::ANSI;

my $uri_escaped = '%C3%9Cberraschungsei+R%C3%B6ntgen';
say $uri_escaped;

my $uri_unescaped = uri_unescape( $uri_escaped );
say $uri_unescaped;

my $utf8_decoded = decode_utf8( $uri_unescaped );
say "Result: $utf8_decoded";
```

---

```
%C3%9Cberraschungsei+R%C3%B6ntgen
"\x{009c}" does not map to cp850 at C:perl.pl line 15.
Ã\x{009c}berraschungsei+RÃ¶ntgen
Result: Überraschungsei+Röntgen
```

With [Win32::Console::ANSI](https://metacpan.org/module/JLMOREL/Win32-Console-ANSI-1.05/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.pm) enabled:

```
%C3%9Cberraschungsei+R%C3%B6ntgen
"\x{009c}" does not map to cp850 at C:perl.pl line 15.
Ç\x{009c}berraschungsei+RÇôntgen
Result: sberraschungsei+R"ntgen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ANSI code page (cp1252) rather than the OEM one.

```
>chcp
Active code page: 437

>perl a.pl cp437
%C3%9Cberraschungsei+R%C3%B6ntgen
Überraschungsei+Röntgen

>perl -MWin32::Console::ANSI a.pl cp1252
%C3%9Cberraschungsei+R%C3%B6ntgen
Überraschungsei+Röntgen
```

Comment: Why does cp850 break the output of `uri_escape`?

Comment: huh? `uri_escape` is not being used, and the result of `uri_escape` (`%C3%9Cberraschungsei+R%C3%B6ntgen`) shows up properly since it's composed exclusively of US-ASCII characters.

Comment: I've mixed it up - I meant why it breaks the result of `uri_unescape`.

Comment: It doesn't at all. `uri_unescape` returns exactly the same thing both times. You break the output by encoding the text returned by `uri_unescape` incorrectly for the tool you use.

Comment: Thx! For some reason I didn't check the strings with `Devel::Peek`.

Comment: Data::Dumper with `local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` would suffice.